# Is there anyway to determine the height of a UIWebView outside of webViewDidFinishLoad:?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. The height of the cell is based on the height of the web view, so I need to know how tall the web view will be after I load an HTML string into it.

Is there anyway to determine the height of the web view before `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is no way. `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is called as soon as the HTML is fully loaded. To determine the height, the HTML has to be completely rendered by the UIWebView. And that can only start **after** the HTML has been loaded.

In fact it may be even worse. Relying on `webViewDidFinishLoad:` to determine the height of the HTML may cause varying results, because the HTML might still have to be rendered when `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is already being called.

To be sure the height is correct you can use the following [method](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/set-the-height-of-a-uiwebview-to-the-height-of-its-html-content/) that I have described a while ago in my blog.